# Override UIViewController init in Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

In Objective-C app I did some custom initialization to `loadData` when class was initialized from another class:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self loadData];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I needed this to add more data:

```
MyViewController *vc = [(MyViewController*)[MyViewController alloc]init];
[vc addMoreData: data];
```

when I try to convert this into *Swift 3*, I am getting confused about how to do it. When I add `init` method it is forcing me to add arguments, which I do not want (or do I?). Also it is making me to add required `init(coder:)`. How can I simply initialize the `ViewController` class and overwrite it inside that `ViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, a class should initialize all the `non-optional` properties  in the `initializer` method, or `non-optional` properties should have default value.

Swift complier forces to add `init?(coder:)`, for classes which conform to `NSCoding` protocol.

```
class MyViewController :UIViewController {

var helpText :String = "" //non-optional property with default value
var data :AnyObject? //Its an optional property, it has nil value by default

init() {

    //initalize all the properties of MyViewController here, before calling super class designated initalizer

    super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)//Designated initializer, pass nil, for both params if not using NIB

    //Now you have access to self
    self.loadData(data: nil)

}



//This method needs to be implemented as UIViewController conform to NSCoding protocol
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func loadData(data :AnyObject?) {
    //Your own implementation
}

func addMoreData(data :AnyObject?) {
    //Your own implementation
}

}
```

Usage:

```
let myViewController = MyViewController()
myViewController.addMoreData(data: nil) //pass your data here
```

Read comments in code snippet, Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        loadData()
    }
}
```

then initialize the viewController like this :

```
let vc = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
vc.addMoreData(data)
```

Hope it helps!